# SPFx Teams app working locally but not working after being installed in Teams

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams, spfx, teams-toolkit, sharepointframework

I have created the SharePoint Framework app for Microsoft Teams.

When I run the app locally, It is working as expected.

But when I generated a package for Teams using Teams Toolkit from VS Code and deployed the same package in Teams. It threw the below error.
[image]

Can anyone help me with the same?

Thanks

Comment: Was there any console log/error you getting?

Comment: No, I am not getting any errors in the console. Thanks

Comment: Could you please try installing the app in different environment to see if the issue persists? This can help determine if the problem is specific to a particular environment or configuration.

Comment: I have tried indifferent 3 environment but face same error. Thanks

Comment: Could you please try to enable logging in your app and check the logs for any error messages or exceptions. This can help identify the specific issue causing the "Something went wrong" error. You can use the `console.log()` function or a logging framework like `winston` to log relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason I have noticed before is that deployment of the app package to the app catalog is not done. This means the user just run "provision" but did not run "deploy" in Teams Toolkit before previewing the dev app in Teams. You could click "deploy" in Lifecycle section which will generate the .sppkg file and upload the file to the app catalog automatically for you.

Another possible reason may be a dependency issue, like if the Microsoft Graph Toolkit SharePoint Framework package is needed but not deployed to your app catalog. If that is the case, you could download it from https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/releases and upload it to the SharePoint Online app catalog. To learn more see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-web-part-microsoft-graph-toolkit?WT.mc_id=m365-80548-wmastyka#deploy-the-microsoft-graph-toolkit-sharepoint-framework-package.

You could also post the question here if it is related to Teams Toolkit https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/issues